# Link to image uploaded in S3 bucket does not display image

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Hi Im new to AWS lambda and S3. Im trying to create an API that will allow me to upload an image. I have following lambda code to upload the file. After upload i see that the file size is correct but the file is corrupted.

```
let encodedImage = event.body;
console.log(encodedImage);
let decodedImage = Buffer.from(encodedImage, "binary");
console.log(decodedImage.length);

const filePath = `${Date.now()}.jpg`;
const params = {
    Bucket: "manufacturer-theme-assets",
    Key: filePath,
    "Body": decodedImage,
    ContentType: "image/jpeg",
    ACL: "public-read"
};
s3.putObject(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        callback(err, null);
    } else {
        let response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            "body": JSON.stringify(data)
            "isBase64Encoded": false
        };
        callback(null, response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using relevant content type for the image, and please share the corrupted image link from S3 or error which you get while opening the file

Else try this first place and check:

```
const filePath = `${Date.now()}.jpg`;    
var params = {
      ACL: "public-read", 
      Body: "decodedImage", 
      Bucket: "manufacturer-theme-assets", 
      Key: filePath
     };
s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response
```